# How to search in a SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm making a database for storing the information of the contacts. Because I'm new to android, I used a code found from the Internet. However, it has errors and when run it app crashes.

Here is the code for database :

#### Storage Manipulator

```
public class FriendStorage extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public FriendStorage(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

public static final String Database_name = "net.Friend.db";
public static final int Database_version = 1;

public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String Table_Friend = "Table_friend";
public static final String Username = "username";
public static final String PhoneNumber = "phoneNumber";

private static final String TABLE_FRIEND_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Friend
                + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + Username + " VARCHAR(25), "
                + PhoneNumber + " VARCHAR(25)";

public static final String Table_Friend_Drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + Table_Friend;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_FRIEND_CREATE);
}

public void insert(String username, String phoneNumber){
    long rowId;
    try {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Username, username);
        contentValues.put(PhoneNumber, phoneNumber);
        rowId = db.insert(Table_Friend, null, contentValues);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Cursor get(){
    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM" + Table_Friend;
    cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor Update(String preUsername, String prePhoneNumber, String newUsername, String newPhoneNumber){
    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String updateTable = "UPDATE" + Table_Friend + "SET" + Username + " = " + newUsername
            + "AND" + PhoneNumber + " = " + newPhoneNumber + "WHERE" + Username + " = "
            + preUsername + "AND" + PhoneNumber + " = " + prePhoneNumber;
    cursor = db.rawQuery(updateTable, null);
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(Table_Friend_Drop);
}

}
```

and in the Main Activity i use **get** function to search in database.

#### MainActivity

```
FriendStorage friendInfoStorage = new FriendStorage(this, "net.Friend.db", null, 1);
cursor = friendInfoStorage.get();
int noOfFriends = 0;
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while ((!cursor.isAfterLast()) && (noOfFriends < cursor.getCount())) {
        if (noOfFriends == 0) {
            Myself.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
            Myself.setPhone_Number(cursor.getString(2));
        } else {
            User.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
            User.setPhone_Number(cursor.getString(2));
            Friends.add(User);
        }
        noOfFriends++;
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
friendInfoStorage.close();
```

**Error is this :**

```
07-12 03:11:14.024 14157-14157/net.network.alire.clientchat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: net.network.alire.clientchat, PID: 14157
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.network.alire.clientchat/net.network.alire.clientchat.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Table_friend (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username VARCHAR(25), phoneNumber VARCHAR(25)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
                                                                           Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Table_friend (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username VARCHAR(25), phoneNumber VARCHAR(25)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:891)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:502)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                                              at net.network.alire.toolBox.FriendStorage.onCreate(FriendStorage.java:36)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                                              at net.network.alire.toolBox.FriendStorage.get(FriendStorage.java:56)
                                                                              at net.network.alire.clientchat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

**thanks in advance**

Comment: Can you provide StackTrace from LogCat? It's hard to help you without knowing an exact error when the app crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a ")" missing caracter in your create statement.
2. You should use TEXT instead of varchar with SQLite.
3. You should not use AUTOINCREMENT. It is implicitly implemented in the PRIMARY KEY with SQLite.